# Prob. 3, Sec. 29, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The image of a locally compact topological space under a continuous (and open) map

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, compactification

Here is Prob. 3, Sec. 29, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a locally compact space. If $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous, does it follow that $f(X)$ is locally compact? What if $f$ is both continuous and open? Justify your answer.

I know that if $f$ is both continuous and open, then $f(X)$ is locally compact. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236158/image-of-locally-compact-space-under-a-continuous-open-map) is a Math Stack Exchange post containing a proof of how this holds?

What if $f$ is a continuous map that is not open?

I know that there is no such example of a continuous map $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$, though $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not, because every such map is constant, as has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133434/prove-that-if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbq-is-continuous-then-f-is-constant/1133438) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112043/continuous-functions-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbq).

Can we construct a counter-example of a (surjective) mapping $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^\omega$?

After all, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact, whereas $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not, as has been discussed in Example 2, Sec. 29, in Munkres.

Comment: The case with just continuity has plenty of counterexamples: take $X$ discrete (locally compact and any function on $X$ is continuous, so just make $f[X]$ whatever you like, $\Bbb Q$ say, and $X$ countable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma is it really essential to take $X$ countable? I mena what if $X$ is uncountable?

Comment: @HelloDarkness I think your counter-example is correct! So can you please undelete your answer so other people could also review it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just take $Y$ equal to your favourite non-locally compact Hausdorff space and $X$ the same *set* but with the discrete topology on it.

Then taking $f$ to be the identity function, we have that $Y$ is a bijective continuous image of $X$ (what's called a "condensation" of $X$ in a lot of the literature) and $X$ is locally compact, metrisable, etc etc. while $Y$ is not locally compact by our setup.

E.g take $Y=\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb P$ (the irrationals) or $\Bbb R^\omega$ (product, uniform or box topology; all are not locally compact); pick your favourite.

Indeed for open maps the situation is better: $f:X \to Y$ open and continuous, then let $y \in f[X]$ and let $x \in X$ be such that $f(x)=y$. Then in $X$ there is a compact $C$ such that $U \subseteq C$ for some open neighbourhood of $x$ (definition that Munkres gives on p. 182 of your edition). Then $f[C]$ is compact (by continuity of $f$) and contains the open neighbourhood $f[U]$ of $y$ (as $f$ is open). So $f[X]$ is locally compact.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=[1,\infty)$, $Y=\mathbb{R}[X]$, the infinite-dimensional vector space of polynomials with real coefficients, endowed with any norm (so that finite-dimensional subspaces are always closed). Let  $B_n \subset Y$ be the set of polynomials with all coefficients between $-1$ and $1$ and with degree at most $n$.

We know that there are surjective maps $g_n:[0,1] \rightarrow B_n$ with $g_n(0)=g_n(1)=0$.

Indeed, take a Peano curve, ie a continuous surjection $h=(a,b):[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^2$. Then define the continuous surjection $h_n:[0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]^{n+1}$ by $h_n(x)=(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},a(x_n),b(x_n))$. Consider next the maps $p_n=h_n \circ h_{n-1} \ldots \circ h_1$, that are surjective continuous maps $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^{n+1}$.

Next, modify $p_n$ into $q_n$ such that: $q_n(t)=p_n(2t-1/2)$ for $1 \leq 4t \leq 3$, $q_n(t)=(1-4t)u+4tp_n(0)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1/4$, and $q_n(t)=(4t-3)u+(4-4t)p_n(1)$ for $3/4 \leq t \leq 1$, with $u=\frac{1}{2}(1,1,1, \ldots,1)$.

Write $q_n=(c_0,\ldots,c_n)$, define $Q_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_k(t)X^k}$ and finally $g_n(x)=2Q_n(x)-1 \in B_n$.

Define now $f$ so that $f(x)=ng_n(x-n)$ for $x \in [n,n+1]$ for all $n \geq 1$. $f$ is onto and continuous.

Indeed, $f$ is continuous on all the intervals $(n,n+1)$, $n \geq 1$, and has limits left and right at all integers (equal to $0$), so is continuous at all integers too.

However, $f$ has a locally compact domain but not a locally compact image, by Riesz’s theorem, since $Y$ is an infinite-dimensional normed vector space.

Comment: can you please consider editing your answer? Either there is some mistake or some details are missing. Can you please review your post once again?

Comment: Please be more specific about where you think more detail is needed.

Comment: (1) What is $\mathbb{R}[X]$? (2) Please give examples of the surjective maps $g_n \colon [0, 1] \to B_n$ with .... (3) How is $f$ continuous? (4) What is the range of $f$? And finally, (5) how to show that the range of $f$ is not locally compact? Please explain in detail the answer to each of these questions in your answer proper. If possible, please just edit your answer duly to include this detail.

Comment: I edited. Do you have any more questions?

Comment: I have yet to have a carefull look at it after your editing. I'll of course get back to you with my feedback as soon as I do. Thank you so much for your time!